# How to ensure DocumentBeforeSave code runs only on current document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that runs when my document is saved as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838299.aspx, however, this event fires when any open Word document is saved. How do I ensure that it only runs for the document in which the macro is defined?

Edited to add code as requested:

```
Public WithEvents appWord as Word.Application 

Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforeSave _ 
 (ByVal Doc As Document, _ 
 SaveAsUI As Boolean, _ 
 Cancel As Boolean) 

 Dim intResponse As Integer 

 intResponse = MsgBox("Do you really want to " _ 
 & "save the document?", _ 
 vbYesNo) 

 If intResponse = vbNo Then Cancel = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include the code you're using in your question. You can use the EDIT link to do so.

Comment: Added code as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word's `DocumentBeforeSave` event provides the `Doc` parameter, which carries the document that triggered the event. Test whether that's the Document object in which you're interested. From your question, it seems the macro is part of the document, so something like:

```
If Doc Is ThisDocument Then Doc.Save
```